# How I can use the Zend framework database classes in core php project --

Tags: php, zend-framework

How I can use the Zend database classes in core php project --

I downloaded  ZendFramework-2.3.1
extracted Zend folder from its library folder to my project library folder --

projectdir/
     library
     -- Zend
     index.php

In index.php I am using this code --

```
use library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter ;
// use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter ; also tried this line

 $adapter = new Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Sqlite',
    'hostname'=>'localhost',
    'database' => 'pub_crawl',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'Micro123#'
    )
);
```

I have also tried this --

```
$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Sqlite',
    'hostname'=>'localhost',
    'database' => 'pub_crawl',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'Micro123#'
 ));

 $adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Sqlite',
    'hostname'=>'localhost',
    'database' => 'pub_crawl',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'Micro123#'
 ));

 $adapter = new library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Sqlite',
    'hostname'=>'localhost',
    'database' => 'pub_crawl',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'Micro123#'
 ));

$adapter = new Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Sqlite',
    'hostname'=>'localhost',
    'database' => 'pub_crawl',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'Micro123#'
    )
);

print_r($adapter) ;
```

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter not found in /var/www/pubcrawl/index.php on line 25

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Somewhere along the way in your project you have to [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the Zend Framework classes you want to use, before you can invoke them.

Comment: you need to use `require` or register an autoloader!

Comment: @ThiagoFrança I was looking for autoloader but I was unable to find that file in the package

Comment: @Abhishek look at [zend framework manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html)

Comment: Thank you @ThiagoFrança for your help, I will try it although I searched for autoloader but unable to find , I will give another try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my prob. by doing this with help of references provided above by  Thiago França in comments --

and was able to get connection of database using Pdo_Mysql as driver and data from tables.

just putted Zend folder at root inside project directory --

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister' => true));

$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
// Register with spl_autoload:
$loader->register();

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter ;

$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
    'hostname'=>'localhost',
    'database' => 'pub_crawl',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'Micro123#'
 ));

$optionalParameters = array();

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM pubs' ;

$statement = $adapter->createStatement($sql, $optionalParameters);

$result = $statement->execute();

$row = $result->current() ; // for getting first record
```

hope it may help someone.